# How to make a bison binary with portable dataroot path

Tags: linux, bison, m4

Building [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) from source, can be done with the usual `./configure && make && make install`.

My job is to build bison binary that can be used on other machines as well.

To specify bison build path, one can use the `--prefix` parameter, e.g

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/users/yuhao10/bison-3.4/output
```

The built bison file tree looks like this:

```
├── bin
│   ├── bison
│   └── yacc
├── lib
│   └── liby.a
└── share
    ├── bison
    │   ├── m4sugar
    │   │   ├── foreach.m4
    │   │   └── m4sugar.m4
```

with many unimportant files omitted.

The problem is, the built `bison` binary always looks for the `m4sugar` files from the same absolute path that it's built into.

If `bison` is put in some random path on other machines, it will report

```
./bison: /home/users/yuhao10/bison-3.4/output/share/bison/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4: cannot open: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to build or run `bison` that loos for the data files like `m4sugar` from a relative path?

Comment: could you have a look at the file /home/users/yuhao10/bison-3.4/output/share/bison/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4 ? Does it exist ? I suspect that it exists, but cannot be run because of a wrong CPU architecture (use `file /home/users/yuhao10/bison-3.4/output/share/bison/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4` to check this).